# Getting context of foreground activity

Tags: android

I want to pop-up a `dialog` when specific event occurred.
The problem is that my application won't be in the foreground when the event will occur, therefore if I use my activity context, the dialog will be popped-up only in my application and not in the foreground application.

How can I pop-up my `dialog` in the foreground application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I pop-up my dialog in the foreground application?

You can convert your dialog into a dialog-themed activity, using `Theme.Dialog`, `Theme.Holo.Dialog`, `Theme.Material.Dialog`, and so on. Then, show that activity.

You cannot get the `Context` of the foreground activity, as that is from another app in another process.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, let's say the event has occurred and I built the dialog inside my application, now I got my `AlertDialog dialog`. What should I do now?

Comment: @Hammer: You do nothing. I mean, you can wrap that in a `DialogFragment` and `show()` it, but it will not appear until your activity returns to the foreground. If you want to have your UI appear to the user over what they are doing, your choices are a `Notification` or an `Activity`. You can make an `Activity` *look* like a dialog via your choice of theme. For example, most system "dialogs" are really activities. All that being said, I strongly recommend that you use a `Notification` (perhaps a high-priority one, for a "heads-up" effect on Android 5.0+), as users don't like being interrupted.

Comment: Cool, got you. Thanks!